# Using linq query on ObservableCollection of interface?

Tags: c#, linq, interface, observablecollection

I have a class, which implements a Interface:

```
class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    public Name { get; set;}

    // bunch of other stuff...
}
```

In my code I would like to remove one item from a Collection like this:

```
ObservableCollection<IMyInterface> MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<IMyInterface>();
// fill collection and do some other stuff...

// Trying to remove one item based on the Name property of the object. 
// At this point I already know, that my collection of IMyInterface is actually a
// collection of MyClass
MyCollection.Remove(c => c.Name == "SomeName");
```

This gives me the following error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'IMyInterface' because it is not a delegate type

Is there a way to use linq expressions on such a Collection of Interfaces?

**Follow-Up Question:**

In case the `Name` property wouldn't exist in the Interface (so it only occurs in `MyClass`), what would be the way to go, to achieve the above? I tested around with different casts (casting the whole collection to `ObservableCollection<MyClass>`, casting within the linq query), but not with much success.

Comment: `MyClass mc = (MyClass)MyCollection.Where(x=>x.Name=="SomeName").SingleOrDefault();
 MyCollection.Remove(mc);`

Comment: @MaciejLos thanks, but why doesn't this work directly with `Remove()`?

Comment: Because [Collection<T>.Remove(T) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1.remove?view=netcore-3.1#System_Collections_ObjectModel_Collection_1_Remove__0_) needs item of specific type instead of `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: Thank you, I think I got it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remove method expects an object of type IMyInterface.
You should delete an item this way :

```
MyCollection.Remove(MyCollection.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "SomeName"));
```

Follow-Up response :

In case there is another property on MyClass that is not on the interface, you will need some conversion  :

```
var myClassCollection = MyCollection.ToList().ConvertAll(c => (MyClass)c);
var itemTobeRemove = myClassCollection.FirstOrDefault(c => c.OtheProp == "test");
MyCollection.Remove(itemTobeRemove);
```